# Bootstrap Responsive - How to force row to bottom when resizing window

Tags: html, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have a row of 6 buttons, with each button in a span2 div like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span2">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Contact", "Home")" class="detailsBtn"><i class="icon-eye-open icon-large"></i> Arrange a Viewing</a>
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Contact", "Home")" class="detailsBtn"><i class="icon-mobile-phone icon-large"></i> Request a Callback</a>
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
         <a href="#" class="detailsBtn"><i class="icon-globe icon-large"></i> View Location Map</a>
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
         <a data-lightbox="fp" href="@Model.Property[0].Floorplan&width=1500" class="detailsBtn"><i class="icon-file-alt icon-large"></i> View Floorplan</a>
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
        <a href="@Model.Property[0].Brochure" target="_blank" class="detailsBtn"><i class="icon-file-text-alt icon-large"></i> View Brochure</a>
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
        @if(Model.Property[0].VirtualTour != null) {
            <a href="@Model.Property[0].VirtualTour" class="detailsBtn"><i class="icon-youtube-play icon-large"></i> Virtual Tour</a>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently when I resize the window, the buttons appear at the top, before any of the content (row by row) like so:

Button 1
Button 2
Button 3
..

I just need to know if there is a way to force this row to start after the content below using twitter bootstrap responsive? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want the navigation to appear after the content when the browser is resized? It's best to have the nav at the top first, that way visitors don't have to scroll past all the content to get to the navbar when they could just click it the second it loads if it was at the top.

Comment: This isn't a navigation bar. These are simply buttons which appear between the navigation bar and the content below (which consists of property information). I just need to know how I can push these down to the bottom as I'd like the mobile visitors to see the property info first before deciding to click a botton.

Comment: Consider having another identical buttons container div at the bottom of the page as well with style: `display:none;`. And, then using media queries make one of the 2 divs visible as required.

Comment: Yes that's what I decided to do eventually.Thanks' srvikram13.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can achieve this by not using bootstrap at all.

Just put your buttons row inside a container and give it the following style it like:

```
<style>
.buttons-wrap,
.content-wrap {
float:right;
}
</style>


<div class="content-wrap">
content here
</div>
<div class="buttons-wrap">
buttons code here
</div>
```

Careful to put them in the order as mentioned.